# pypi package isn't installing with all the files?

Tags: python, pypi

I am writing my first package to be shared on the pypi database...

It took me a lot of fiddling to get everything to package correctly, but I finally did.

I have a structure like this.

```
---dist
---package.egg-info
---MANIFEST.in
---setup.py
---package/
   ---__init__.py
   ---file.py
   ---info.txt
   ---templates/
      ---template.html
```

now in my dist folder when I extract the tar.gz file I see everything. but when I run a pip install package then I only get the egg and the **init**.py and file.py files and not the other text files and template files.

Why is this?

Setup.py added...:

```
setup(name='django-g-recaptcha',
      version='0.1.2',
      description='Django view decorator to validate google recaptcha forms',
      url='https://bitbucket.org/deltaskelta/django-g-recaptcha-validate/overview',
      author='Jeff Willette',
      author_email='jrwillette88@gmail.com',
      keywords = ['django', 'recaptcha', 'catpcha'],
      packages = ['g_recaptcha',],
)
```

Comment: Please provide your `setup.py` code, without that it's just guessing. However, depending on setting pip installs 'data' files to directory for data on particular system, and not inside your package's directory in site-packages.

Comment: added to post. I was under the assumption tht MANIFEST.in took care of adding data files instead of setup.py, since I structured it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `include_package_data = True` to `setup()` arguments:

```
setup(name='django-g-recaptcha',
      version='0.1.2',
      description='Django view decorator to validate google recaptcha forms',
      url='https://bitbucket.org/deltaskelta/django-g-recaptcha-validate/overview',
      author='Jeff Willette',
      author_email='jrwillette88@gmail.com',
      keywords = ['django', 'recaptcha', 'catpcha'],
      packages = ['g_recaptcha',],
      include_package_data = True
)
```

This should help, however I suggest to also use `package_data` along with your `MANIFEST.in`. And also you might want to add a setting specifying, that your package is intended to be used with Django.

See https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html for more information.

Comment: what django specifying setting are you speaking of? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: `install_requires` see Declaring Dependencies on the link in the answer. Also `framework`, but it's less important, it's more like META-DATA, that will help people find your app.

Comment: ok thanks, the wording was making me think it was something else

Comment: Sorry that I confused you, my English is far from perfect. :)